# Character indexed series groupby non-spaces

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a series that looks like the below. Ideally, I'd like to perform a groupby operation that finds the mean of each 'word' in the series (basically each contiguous string of the index that is separated by a space).

```
b    0.240322
u    0.279720
f    0.329494
f    0.359549
a    0.371886
l    0.378648
o    0.379713
     0.352408
b    0.350311
i    0.322337
l    0.290646
l    0.265696
s    0.249698
     0.224883
r    0.228836
a    0.239643
n    0.247804
c    0.243472
h    0.257716
```

And this would be translated to:

```
buffalo  0.334
bills    0.296
ranch    0.243
```

Comment: how do you get `0.288` as a mean value from `buffalo`?

Comment: I made that up. Just an example

Comment: Fixed the numbers

Answer (score 0):

We can make `index` a column with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), create groups based on where there is a space character and use [`groupby aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to join the words and take the averages, then restore the `index` with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
# Make Index a Column
df = df.reset_index()
# Boolean Index on where spaces are
m = df['index'].eq(' ')
# Groupby Aggregate
df = (
    df.groupby(
        # Groups of words separated by space (excluding the spaces)
        m.cumsum().mask(m),
        as_index=False
    ).agg({
        'index': ''.join,  # Make Words
        'num': 'mean'  # Take Average
    }).set_index('index').rename_axis(None)  # Make index column the index
)
```

`df`:

```
              num
buffalo  0.583445
bills    0.349003
ranch    0.498625
```

---

Sample DataFrame used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx = 'buffalo bills ranch'
np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': np.random.random(len(idx))}, index=list(idx))
```

`df`:

```
        num
b  0.221993
u  0.870732
f  0.206719
f  0.918611
a  0.488411
l  0.611744
o  0.765908
   0.518418
b  0.296801
i  0.187721
l  0.080741
l  0.738440
s  0.441309
   0.158310
r  0.879937
a  0.274086
n  0.414235
c  0.296080
h  0.628788
```